# Placing text over any image at "compass" positions

Tags: html, css

Say you have a JPEG image with an arbitrary width and height in a HTML document, and you want to place the words "North", "South", "East" and "West" over the image like on a compass.

Pseudo code to explain the positions:

- North: X=image.width/2, Y=margin
- South: X=image.width/2, Y=image.height-margin
- East: Y=image.height/2, X=image.width-margin
- West: Y=image.height/2, X=margin

How do you accomplish this *without using any JavaScript*, only CSS. That is, the NSEW labels are always in the expected positions for all image sizes.

Comment: Please next time show some HTML, CSS of what you currently have / have tried!

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly straight forward using absolute positioning on the labels. You can then apply the top/right/bottom/left positioning properties for each label as required. As long as we can define the dimensions of the labels then it becomes really easy to perfectly position them. In this example each label is 20px by 20px so i just adjust the margin for each so that they are perfectly positioned.

You can play around with the image dimensions and the labels always display correctly.

```
.north-label {
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
.south-label {
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
.east-label {
    right:0;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
.west-label {
    left:0;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

In terms of the "margin" you've outlined in your question's psudeo-code, just add that in place of the 0 used for top/right/bottom/left. So if you want N to be 10px from the edge, change top:0; to top:10px;

https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/xz0ojfft/

Comment: `display:block;` and `vertical-align:middle;` on an absolute positioned element? https://jsfiddle.net/xz0ojfft/5/

Comment: Fair call @RokoC.Buljan Obviously display:block isn't required. And I didnt know vertical align had no effect. cheers

Comment: This works great! However: Is there anyway to automatically center all the four texts horizontally around an anchor point (so that they expand to both sizes if increasing the font size for example). Right now they seem to be left-aligned no matter what I do and I found myself having to manually adjust margins to pixel perfection to get the correct placement (which will fail when changing/translating the NSEW words). As far as I can tell text-align and vertical-align seem to do nothing for the final result.

Comment: Inside the spans, add another span and use position:relative then adjust the left/right positions to -50%. https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/xz0ojfft/20/